# A function that returns a username

Tags: php

Hi,

What's wrong with my function? It seems it's not working but I don't know why. The function is supposed to return a username:

```
function getusername($username) {
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$username."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    return $row['$username'];
```

When I use it in this code, its not returning anything:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    // Check to see if the person accessing this page is logged in
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 'post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'\" /><hr />"; } else { echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply.</p><hr /></td></tr>"; }
    // Fetch all the topic data from the database
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        // Query the posts table for all posts in the specified topic
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND topic_id='".$tid."'";
        // Execute the SELECT query
        $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
        // Fetch all the post data from the database
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
            // Echo out the topic post data from the database
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid blue;'><div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />by ".getusername($row2['post_creator'])." - ".convertdate($row2['post_date'])."<hr />".$row2['post_content']."</div></td><td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid blue;'>User Info Here</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
```

Comment: Its worth noting that this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should ensure that user input is sanitised, preferably use a prepare statement, so that data, is separate from the query itself.

Comment: But you're learning bad practices

Answer (score 3):

You should change `return $row['$username'];` to `return $row['username'];`

Comment: its not working if i remove the dollar sign

Comment: So it doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

## USE PDO.

You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

If I can find a way to get you to look up `';DROP TABLE users;--` then I can give you a very bad day. Hint: Can I select a category or a topic number using `$_GET` vars?

### You should also use JOIN

Doing one query against the database is better than 10:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.username FROM posts
JOIN users ON (users.username = posts.post_creator)
WHERE category_id=:category_id AND topic_id=:topic_id
```

#### Dollar sign is a PHP thing, not a MySQL thing.

```
return $row['$username'];
```

should be:

```
return $row['username'];
```

Comment: not working if i remove the dollar sign

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling mysql_connect and mysql_select_db in your code?

In my experience it is best to call the connect function as soon as possible and load the returned resource into a global variable so that it may be used in all of your functions. For example:

```
global $dbHandle;
$dbHandle = mysql_connect("server string");
```

Then your function would look something like this:

```
function getusername($username) {
global $dbHandle;
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$username."' LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $dbHandle) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
return $row['$username'];
}
```